# turn 'only render' on, play animation, turn 'only render' off when done playing

Tags: python, animation, scripting

I'd like to set up a python script that will

- turn 'show only render' on
- play animation
- then upon stopping (or
  esc), stop the animation and turn 'show only render' off.

Ideally this would work for viewport playback and play blast...

The first two are easy, but I can't figure out how to get 'show only render' to turn off after stopping the animation. Any ideas, suggestions... ?